# Generating a Temporary url in Python

Tags: python, encryption, hash, hyperlink, temporary

I've been trying to generate a temporary url in python, the url will some data that i need to make sure isn't changed so i'll add a hash in the end but i keep ending with a bString no matter what i try, can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong?
Here's a sample of my code
oh and i know that maybe changing the algorithms/encoding might solve the problem but i can't find a suitable one, can any downvoter explain why he downvoted

```
import hashlib
import datetime
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def checkTemp(tempLink):
    encrypter = AES.new('1234567890123456', AES.MODE_CBC, 'this is an iv456')
    decryption = encrypter.decrypt(tempLink)
    length = len(decryption)

    hash_code = decryption[length-32:length]
    data= decryption[:length-32].strip()
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()
    hasher.update(data)
    hashCode = hasher.digest()

    if(hash_code==hashCode):
        array = data.decode().split(",",5)
        print("expiry date is :"+ str(array[5]))
        return array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4]
    else:
        return "","","","",""

def createTemp(inviter,email,role,pj_name,cmp_name):
    delim = ','
    data = inviter+delim+email+delim+role+delim+pj_name+delim+cmp_name+delim+str(datetime.datetime.now().time())
    data = data.encode(encoding='utf_8', errors='strict')

    hasher = hashlib.sha256()
    hasher.update(data)

    hashCode = hasher.digest()
    encrypter = AES.new('1234567890123456', AES.MODE_CBC, 'this is an iv456')
    # to make the link a multiple of 16 by adding for AES with the addition of spaces
    newData = data+b' '*(len(data)%16)
    result = encrypter.encrypt(newData+hashCode)

    return result
#print(str(link).split(",",5))
link = createTemp("name","email@homail.com","Designer","Project Name","My Company")
print(link)
inviter,email,role,project,company = checkTemp(link)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question reads like someones stream of consciousness. Add some punctuation, sentence stops, and capitalization to help the reader parse what you've written above.

Comment: @Hooked thanks, well i'm kind of new so i'm not really good at posting my thoughts, plus i was abit frustrated and lost trying to fix it, made me more confused. 
anyways thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not being able to putout a normal string because the encryption will result in characters that are almost impossible to encode, so the solution is to use binascii to encode the bStrings for us and decode them

```
import binascii
```

then we encode the resulting usable string for the link

```
hexedLink = binascii.hexlify(link).decode()
```

and we unhexify it before using it in the method

```
inviter,email,role,project,company = checkTemp(binascii.unhexlify(hexedLink))
```